# Android: VideoView setOnErrorListener called only once

Tags: android, android-videoview

Below is the piece of my code for handling the error of my video player. This error callback listener gets triggered for the first time only. After that, it's not capturing the error.

```
videoPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getResources().getString(R.string.msgPleaseNoConnection),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        vVideoBufferLoader.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Note:

I tried returning **true** from that callback which means I handled the error. But it doesn't solve the problem too.

Answer (score 1):

The goal of the MediaPlayer's OnErrorListener is to signal when an error has occurred, at which point the MediaPlayer object is in an end state.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

If you are using the MediaPlayer constructor to 'reset' the object elsewhere in the code, you are essentially creating a new MediaPlayer object and saving it over the older one.  If this is the case, then you also need to reassign the OnErrorListener.

Here's a short snippet of how I've been using OnErrorListener in my app:

```
private MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener vidVwErrorListener = new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {       //if there was an error in trying to play the intro video
        if (tryLrgClip) {           // If the larger-resolution clip failed to play, try playing the backup (lower-resolution) clip.
            tryLrgClip = false;
            trySmClip = true;
            vidVwSplashView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + SPLASH_VIDEOS));
            vidVwSplashView.start();
        } else {                    // If that didn't work either, give up on playing a video, and do something else
            tryLrgClip = trySmClip = false;
            vidVwSplashView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //Something else
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

I hope that helps!